Why is electric flux different from the mathematical definition of flux?
Mathematically, the flux of any quantity $q$ that flows is defined to be
$$\frac{\mathrm dq/\mathrm dt}{\text{Area}}$$
However, electric flux is the scalar product of the electric field and area $E\cdot A$.
These two are clearly different, as the first should give (taking $q$ as charge) current per unit area, but the second gives field strength times area. I don't understand if/how the general definition applies to this case, thanks for the help.

They are two different "fluxes" and the problem is due to an abuse of notation due to the English words "flux", "current" etc. being used interchangeably. The English Wikipedia article on "flux" has a description of this issue.
Your first definition is the current of a scalar quantity crossing a given surface $A$, so basically you are couting how many electrons (in your case) cross the surface $A$ in a time $dt$. It's indeed the current.
The second definition with a slight abuse of notation (because the electric field does not "flow"), is the flux of a vector field, telling you (at a given time) how many vectors "enter" and "exit" a given surface. It is not the same thing as the current, despite both somehow being a "flux", as the vectors are not "entering and exiting" the surface by moving over time: they are fixed there and you just count how many are pointing in and how many are pointing out. It is in a way a "static current of vectors".
If you are looking at the transport of something (e.g. of electrons like in a current) you use the first definition (it would be better to call it "current"). If you are looking at a vector field and you are interested in knowing how many "vectors" enter and exit a surface (without flowing, just some are pointing in and some are pointing out) then use the second definition.
There is a bit of relation between the two things, since if you consider current a vector (actually, a current density) telling you how many electrons are flowing in a given direction per unit time and per unit area, then the flux of this current (density) will tell you how much the number of electrons inside the surface is changing as $N_1$ of them flow in and $N_2$ flow out, i.e. it is telling you whether the total charge inside the surface is increasing or decreasing or staying the same.
So: transport is associated with a current (first definition). The flux of this current is telling you the net amount of mass changing inside this surface.
In the specific case of current in a wire the current density is proportional to the local electric field in the wire (Ohm's law, in differential form) so the electric flux is indeed proportional to the current flowing in the wire (and the proportionality constant takes care of the dimensional issue you are dealing with): but this is a special case because in electromagnetism the electric flux and the charge are connected by Gauss's law!

So are the two things in fact different, and when we apply the first definition to electricity, we get that quantity is current per unit area?

The first definition gives current per unit area j=I/A, yes, if q is charge then that is electrical current per unit area. Its flux (j*A=I) is the current through a given surface. Turns out that in specific cases j~E (j is proportional to E) so that the flux of j (the current) is [proportional to] the electric flux, but this is not  a general situation for "fluxes" and "currents".
